# Find number of higher values than the given value in BST

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to find number of higher values than the given value in a binary search tree just for fun and overlearning. I have written a resursive function so far by drawing on paper with its logic. However, when I run it, it doesn't give the expected result. For example, `30, 25, 98, 23, 28, 97, 99, 29` is contained in BST. I'm trying to get greater values than `28` should be `5`, but output is `2`. Where is the problem in the method? I'm traversing all nodes in the tree, is there a more efficient solution for it?

```
public int findMax(Node<E> localRoot, E target) {
        if (localRoot == null) return 0;

        int cmpResult = target.compareTo(localRoot.data);
        int valL = findMax(localRoot.left, target) + cmpResult < 0 ? 1 : 0;
        int valR = findMax(localRoot.right, target) + cmpResult < 0 ? 1 : 0;
        return valL + valR;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the first function call will always return at most 1 + 1 because of this logic:

```
int valL = findMax(localRoot.left, target) + cmpResult < 0 ? 1 : 0;
int valR = findMax(localRoot.right, target) + cmpResult < 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

It doesn't matter how many levels it calls down because of the order of operations. valL and valR will always be either 0 or 1 because it is testing whether (findMax(localRoot.right, target) + cmpResult) is < 0, ten assigning a value  a of 0 or 1. Try it using parentheses so that you are adding to the results of `findMax`. Like this:

```
int valL = findMax(localRoot.left, target) + (cmpResult < 0 ? 1 : 0);
int valR = findMax(localRoot.right, target) + (cmpResult < 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

--EDIT--

Okay, I realized that I missed another important issue: you are adding the local comparison result to the left and right calculations for each node. This will result in a value that is too high! You need to keep the local node comparison independent of the left and right node comparisons. Try this:

```
int cmpResult = target.compareTo(localRoot.data);
int localNodeVal = cmpResult < 0 ? 1 : 0; // This is the value for the current node by itself.
int valL = findMax(localRoot.left, target);
int valR = findMax(localRoot.right, target);
// Add the local node result with the evaluation of the left and right side.
return localNodeVal + valL + valR;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't understand why it results in just 2. However, my method works wrong interestingly even after changed to parentheses.

Comment: I just noticed also that you're adding the local node result to both the left and the right side. You should only add the local node result once. Add the left and right side to 0 or 1 based on the local node result. I can look at this more in about 30 minutes. Sorry can't do more right now.

Comment: Could you edit your answer according to your reply please?

Comment: I apologize for the rough answers early on - I was on my cell phone and couldn't do any real verification. I have tested this and it seems to give the expected result. Good luck!